# Graphing per-user CPU usage on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, graph, cpu-usage, performance-monitoring

I want to graph (graphical output would be great, i.e. a .png file) the following situation: I have users A, B, and C. I limit their resources so that when all users run a CPU intensive task at the same time, those processes will use 25%, 25%, and 50% of CPU. I know I can get the real-time stats using `top` but have no idea what to do with them. I've searched through the huge `top` man page but haven't found much on the subject of outputting data that can be graphed. Ideally, the graph would show a span of maybe 30 seconds. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Flagged. Though, just collecting the raw data somehow would be great. I know you can do it with `virt-top` (something like `virt-top -d $DELAY --csv $CSVFILE --script`) but haven't found the equivalent for `top`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know I can get the real-time stats using top but have no idea what
>   to do with them

Batch mode could be useful:

```
   -b : Batch mode operation
        Starts  top  in ’Batch mode’, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or
        to a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit  you’ve  set
        with the ’-n’ command-line option or until killed.
```

For example:

```
$ top -b -n 1 -u <user> | awk 'NR > 7 { sum += $9 } END { print sum }'
```

[Ganglia Gmetric](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/gmetric_spoofing) can be used to plot a graph for this.

**`cpu_per_user_gmetric.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
USERS="a b c"

for user in $USERS; do
    /usr/bin/gmetric --name CPU_per_"$user"_user --value `top -b -n 1 -u $user | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }'` --type uint8 --unit Percent
done
```

**`crontab -l`**

```
* * * * * /path/to/cpu_per_user_gmetric.sh
```

and here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `tload` command represents the pictorial representation of the average system load through ASCII graph. This command can be used to provide the graph on a terminal. The syntax for the command is:

```
tload [options] [terminal]
```

If terminal is not provided as the argument to this command, then by default it outputs the graph on the current terminal. So the simplest forms of this command are:

```
$ tload
```

- See more at: http://linoxide.com/monitoring-2/tload-command-displays-current-system-load-average-on-linux/#sthash.hYOvoF40.dpuf

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use `collectd` and adapt one of the [available plugins](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Table_of_Plugins)? Yes, none of the listed will do exactly what you want, but on the other hand they are pretty simple to modify and I think you could start with for example `processes` plugin and start working from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sar` and `sadf` to gather and prepare the data for easy graphing. http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html

Comment: I did check out `sar` but could not find a way to associate a process with a specific user, any ideas?