# Simple tools to quickly capture and graph some arbitrary metrics on a server?

Tags: metrics, graph

I want something that's quick to set up, doesn't have a lot of dependencies, outputs pretty graphs, and is easily customizable (e.g. calling external scripts that simply output a numerical value).

I've worked with Munin and Zabbix before, but feel that they're both a bit too involved for my needs (especially Zabbix), and am wondering what else is out there. I don't want to use something low-level like rrdtool because I use it rarely enough that I keep forgetting the syntax.

My plan right now is to use this to collect some stats on the usage of a website, by graphing certain values from SQL queries every few minutes or so. Maybe there are even tools built specifically for this kind of database usage analysis?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/417307/59925

Answer (score 3):

The best I have used so far is [Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) hands down.  It supports almost an endless amount of metrics.  We looked at several other options including the ones mentioned here but ultimately decided upon Observium.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to run the scripts (which extract the data) on your hosts, you can easily send the values via http (e.g. via curl) to metric services like (list incomplete):

[Stathat](http://stathat.com)

[Librato](http://metrics.librato.com)

[New Relic](http://newrelic.com)

..and so on.

I can't say which one is the best since I just started to check them out for my use cases not long ago. Having used Nagios for a long time, these services are like a bright light at the end of the monitoring tunnel.

Answer (score -1):

I guess [cacti](http://cacti.net) is your friend, its easy to setup has the ability to call external scripst and makes nice graphs out of the box for common system metrics.
Give it a try.